# why 'jquery animate callBack function dont work inside other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am currently new to javascript and jquery,
im trying to animate page transitions as you see in the code i have added. everything is working as expected until the activation of the callback function in 'jquery.animate' inside the 'openNavPages()' function.
i will be grateful if somebody will explain to me what am i doing wrong.
p.s: i have looked for similar questions but i haven`t found an answer that gave me a solution.

```
/*! navigate links */
var Dictionary = [["home","home.html"], ["about","about.html"]
];
$('nav ul li a').click(function(){
var id = this.id;
// find the button that clicked and navigate to the url
for (i=0; i<Dictionary.length; i++){
    if(id==Dictionary[i][0]){
        openNavPages(Dictionary[i][1]);
        }

    }
});
 // function to navigate pages
function openNavPages(url){
var page = url;

$('#main').animate({opacity: '0'},800,function(page){
    window.location.href = page;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the inner callback function with a `page` parameter.  jQuery doesn't pass any arguments to this function when it calls it, so this parameter isn't set.  Since it's there, and it has the same name, your inner function uses this undefined variable rather than the one in the outer scope.

To fix it, simply remove this parameter:

```
function openNavPages(url){
    var page = url;
    $('#main').animate({opacity: '0'},800,function(){
        window.location.href = page;
    });
}
```

You could do away with the `page` variable entirely though, and just use the `url` parameter of the outer function directly:

```
function openNavPages(url){
    $('#main').animate({opacity: '0'},800,function(){
        window.location.href = url;
    });
}
```

Comment: hi james,tnx for your response,  i tried your solution but it doesn't seem to work there is no animation and no nevigation...

Comment: @Jonathan Just caught up with this.  Probably because I missed your other problem of the missing `$` as specified in your answer.  Have edited mine to suit too.

Answer (score 0):

OK. very embarrassing i forgot the $ sign here: ('#main').animate({opacity: '0'},800,function()
took me an hour to discover that...must get some sleep (-: